# Not able to populate textarea value if it's updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On click of a button, I am showing a popup with one text area and a submit button.

I am able to enter a value in the `textarea` (e.g.: "hello1"), and when clicking on the submit button, I am checking the textarea's entered value, it gives me "hello1", and fades out the pop up. (as expected)

**Issue**: the second time, I click the same button again, I entered the value "hello2", and after submitting, it shows me the last entered value in an alert and fades out.

Below is my code:

```
function onCalChange(cal) {
    // inputField = cal.inputField;
    startDate = cal.date;
    var calVal = this.id;
    popup2(calVal);
}

function popup2(calVal) {
    idValue = calVal.split("-");
    $('.popup2').css('display','block');
    //$('.popup2').addClass('pop_up_bckgd');
    $(".popup2").append("<div class='pop_up_bckgd'></div>");
    $(".popup2").append("<div class='pop_up_container'><form>\n\
\n\
\n\
<label  style='margin-left:65px;margin-top:40px;'class = 'label-value' for = 'reason-for-change-" + idValue[2] + "'>Reason for change</label>\n\
<br>\n\
<textarea id='reasontxt" + idValue[2] + "'style = 'width: 74%;margin-left: 62px;height:100px' class = 'text-box' name = 'reason' required></textarea>\n\
<br>\n\
<div style = 'text-align:center'><input class = 'submit-value2' type = 'button' value = 'Submit' name = 'submit1' onclick= 'clicksubmit(idValue[2]);' '></div ></form>")
}

function clicksubmit(id) {

    var idNum= parseInt(id);

    if ($('#reasontxt' + idNum).val() == "") {
        // alert("1");
        $('#reasontxt' + idNum).next(".validation").remove();
        $('#reasontxt' + idNum).after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-top:5px'>Please enter Reason for change Field</div>");               
    }  else {
        alert('2');
        alert($('#reasontxt' + idNum).val());
        $('#reason' + (idNum)).val($('#reasontxt' + idNum).val());
        //    $('#reasontxt' + idNum).val() == ""
        $('.popup2').fadeOut(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: `onclick= 'clicksubmit(idValue[2]);'` should be `onclick= 'clicksubmit(" + idValue[2] + ");'`

Comment: not working still getting same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making he change specified by erkaner on the comments, I was able to reproduce the issue by copying your code into this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2djohhw/ (I had to make another minor change to hardcode the value of `calVal` for testing).

From what I saw, the issue is:

- Every time that you click on the button, a `form` with a `textarea` and a `submit` button are appended to the popup (using `$(".popup2").append(...)`);
- the `id` of the textarea depends on the `id` of the button that was clicked (`calVal`);
- so if the same button is clicked several times [or the button is different but it has an `id` which third part (as you are splitting it and only using the third value `idValue[2]`) matches the one of a previously clicked button], you will be appending multiple `textarea` over time, all of them with the same `id`.
- when you submit, and read the value of the `textarea`, as there are multiple with the same `id`, the browser will take the value of the first `textarea` with the specified `id`.
- Because of that you get always the same value that is the one of the first `textarea`.

How to fix it? Avoid having multiple elements with the same `id`.

One possible solution: delete the content of the `.popup2` box every time you are going to display it, that way you make sure that the `id` of the textbox is really unique and you don't face unexpected errors:

```
$(".popup2").html("");
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/v2djohhw/1/

If you don't want to (or you cannot) delete the content of the `.popup2` box, and want to show all the previous textareas, another solution would be keeping track of the number of times the button was clicked and add that value into the id of the textarea. That way you'll make sure the textbox id will be really unique.

You can see it on this other fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2djohhw/2/